# Determine Mouse Button Switch State

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mouse, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to determine the host operating system's settings regarding mouse button switch state to properly handle a context menu event.

I want to determine whether or not the operating system my application is running on has switched the left and right mouse buttons, and handle the mouse click event accordingly.

What would be the best way to determine that in C#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch all that, seems like the OS automatically translates which button you're pressing with regards to having them switched.

It's always safe to assume a context menu should open when `MouseButtons.Right` is pressed.

Comment: Ah. I figured you wanted to be able to tell if the right or left button was clicked regardless of whether the button configuration was set to right-handed or left-handed. Too bad - that was a more interesting problem.